# Merging multiple JSON responses from different APIs through python

Tags: json, python-3.x, merge, python-requests

I have 4 different APIs which give JSON responses. I have used python script to take the important values and write that in a CSV file. 
Now, I want to merge all these 4 responses as one JSON which is to be sent to my SIEM tool directly without writing it in CSV. Also, responses have overlapping keys like "id", "name", to name a few.

```
Response to API1:{"result": [{"id": "1d849adb2558840244", "disabled": False, "description": "Origin Error Average 5xx"}
Response to API2:{"result": [{"id": "d0131747581997556", "paused": False, "description": "Apple", "action": "drop"}]}
Response to API3:{"result": {"id": "zap", "value": "on", "modified_on": "2019-10-14T19:32:40.852986Z", "editable": True}}
```

Custom_API.json: Response to API1 + Response to API2 + Response to API3
And, Custom_API.json will be sent to my SIEM tool for analysis.
Please help!

Comment: would this do what you are looking for? `combined = {"result": api1["result"] + api2["result"] + api3["result"] }`. This is just taking the `api["result"]` lists and concatenate them together, then packing it back into an object with a `"result"` field.

Comment: response_result = response['result'] <-- This is coming to be string
response_for_WAF_Status_resultValue = response_for_WAF_Status_parent['result']['value']  <-- This is coming to be string
combined = {"final result": response_rate_control_rc_result + response_for_WAF_Status_resultValue} <-- Can't add like string

Comment: response_result = response['result'] <-- This is coming to be string
response_for_WAF_Status_resultValue = response_for_WAF_Status_parent['result']['value']  <-- This is coming to be string
combined = {"final result": response_rate_control_rc_result + response_for_WAF_Status_resultValue} <-- Can't add string
Then, I tried using:
array_response_result = ast.literal_eval(response_result), which gave me an error ValueError: malformed node or string:. Not sure, what else can I do